# Changing map starting zoom based on device

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google map with a shaded polygon area and a few markers. I set the starting zoom to frame the shaded area nicely on the tablet emulation I'm testing on. When I test on a different emulator (phone for example) the zoom is too close causing the shaded area to fill the screen.

I don't understand how this is not an issue for more people? Or do I really suck at internet search? I can't find anywhere how you change the starting zoom based on what device (and therefore the screen size) and orientation you are viewing the map on?

Code example :

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    float zoom = 15.8f;  // Need to change based on device screen size/orientation
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
       .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-35.237, 149.082976), zoom)));

    // other code
}
```

Sceenshots

[image: Nexus 9 Tablet Emulation]

[image: Nexus 6P Phone Emulation]

OK, tried replacing

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
       .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-35.237, 149.082976), zoom)));
```

with

```
LatLngBounds boundry = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-35.243, 149.074), 
    new LatLng(-35.231, 149.094));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundry,0));
```

Now app crashes on start with "Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0."

Comment: I think the zoom level is a relative thing, i.e. you should be seeing the same map across devices, except with different resolutions.  Is this not the case?

Comment: No, should I post some screenshots?

Comment: Yes, but I think the problem may have to do with other areas of your layout.  However, the issue of landscape versus portrait is real; you'll have to deal with that somehow.

Comment: So the Map size error is because I have to make sure the map has undergone layout. I have no idea what that means or how to sure that my map is layout'ed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sw = new LatLng(-35.243, 149.074);
    LatLng ne = new LatLng(-35.231, 149.094);

    mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            LatLngBounds boundary = new LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundary,90));
        }
    });

    // other code
}
```

Comment: In general, if you implement an answer and then run into a new issue, it's more productive to comment on the original answer than edit the original question. This preserves the integrity of the original question as well as actually notifying the answerer that you need more assistance.

Comment: Ah OK, Sorry and thanks for the advice. First time posting, still have lots to learn.

Comment: In this particular case, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener is the callback that will tell you when the map is laid out. OnMapLoadedCallback is slightly different and is not guaranteed to be called.